# How to use 2TDEA option of 3DES with CommonCrypto

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3des, commoncrypto

When I am encrypting data with CCCrypt() with 3DES algorithm I have to provide 24bytes long key like for 3TDEA option of 3DES. From a reason I have use 2TDEA with 16bytes long key. But when I use 16byte key, CCCrypt() fails. What to do with it?

```
result = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, 
                 kCCAlgorithm3DES, 
                 kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode, 
                 desKey, 
                 24, 
                 nil,
                 dataBlock, 
                 dataBlockSize, 
                 outputData.mutableBytes, 
                 outputData.length, 
                 &outLength);
```

Comment: Don't. [It's obsolete and not secure.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301898398_On_the_security_of_2-key_triple_DES). Get first 8 bytes of the key and append them at the end (xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyy -> xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxx).

Comment: I do not have a choice, it's client's requirement :-/ I have almost no chance to influence how the key will be handled on server. They simply expect 2TDES encryption and the 112bit key delivered in another way. When I encode it this way, they will not decode it by this 112bit key until they adjust algorithm, right?

Comment: [Triple DES - Keying options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) - Keying option 2 - K1 and K2 are independent, and K3 = K1. Sometimes known as 2TDEA or double-length keys.

Comment: Oh my! You are right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Anyone who will read this:

> **It's [obsolete, deprecated and not secure](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301898398_On_the_security_of_2-key_triple_DES).**

### 3DES & 2TDEA

Triple DES = 3DES, TDES, TDEA, Triple DEA. It has many names, but all of them refer to the same cipher. It's a DES applied three times to each data block.

You can visit [Triple DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) article on Wikipedia to learn more about it. Several [Keying options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options) exists and you're interested in the 2nd one:

> K<sub>1</sub> and K<sub>2</sub> are independent, and K<sub>3</sub> =
>   K<sub>1</sub>. Sometimes known as **2TDEA** or double-length keys.
>   This provides a shorter key length of 112 bits and a reasonable
>   compromise between DES and Keying option 1, with the same caveat
>   as above. This is an improvement over "double DES" which only
>   requires 256 steps to attack. NIST has deprecated this option.

You have 16 bytes (K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub>). This keying option says that K<sub>3</sub> = K<sub>1</sub>. Which means that you have to copy the first 8 bytes and append them.

- `AAAAAAAA11111111` (16 bytes, K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub>)
- `AAAAAAAA11111111????????` (24 bytes, K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub>, K<sub>3</sub>?)
- `AAAAAAAA11111111AAAAAAAA` (24 bytes, K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub>, K<sub>3</sub> where K<sub>3</sub> = K<sub>1</sub>)